# Как посмотреть работу Api функции VirtualAlloc на c#

Tags: c#, winapi

Пишу приложение и необходима функция virtualAlloc (api-kernel32)
Так вот, использую коД:
     [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
         static extern IntPtr VirtualAlloc(IntPtr IpAddress, UIntPtr dwSize, AllocationType flAllocationType, MemoryProtection flprotect);

```
     public enum AllocationType
         : uint
     { 
         Commit = 0*1000,
         Reserve = 0*2000
     }
    public enum MemoryProtection
          : uint
     {
         Execute = 0 * 10,
         Execute_ReadWrite = 0 * 40
     }
```

Как удостовериться в её работе?

Answer (score 2):

- *"Удостовериться в работе"* аллокатора невозможно по его определению. Максимум, что вы можете сделать — это по косвенным признакам (типа `AccessViolationException`) понять, что вы что-то делаете не так.
- Тем не менее, вы можете обезопасить себя от некоторой части ошибок, внимательно изучив сигнатуру [нативного `VirtualAlloc'a`,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366887(v=vs.85).aspx) и проверив, что ваше `extern` объявление метода ей соответствует.
- Еще можно не переписывать вручную `enum'ы` типа `AllocationType,` а взять их c [`PInvoke.net,`](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.virtualalloc) тем самым, опять же, уменьшив вероятность ошибки при объявлении `DllImport.`

Comment: Все-таки можно:
PerformanceCounter perfonamcecounter1 = new PerformanceCounter();
                       
            perfonamcecounter1.CategoryName = "Memory";
                       perfonamcecounter1.CounterName = "Committed Bytes";
           Если использовать параметр Commit, то уоличество байтов будет расти.